# Unity button press logs debug lines on console but does not make the functions work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I work on a unity project that has cannon weapon and its own level system. Its job is simple as its script and it works perfectly on key press prints debug logs and calls functions ingame. But I need it to be called by a button press. Button press only calls debug logs of the related functions but cannot actually level up cannon.

In the CannonLevelManager script as you can see both the key press and the button calls TryIncreaseCannonLevel function (it was directly IncreaseCannonLevel(); but it does the same so i tried this approach) and the key press calls every function and debug log perfectly. for button press, it calls  TryIncreaseCannonLevel and prints debug logs as follows:
"Attempting to Increase Cannon Level"
"Increasing Cannon Level"
"Increased Cannon Level"
"UpdateCannonLevel called"
But any function there are not being called and work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class CannonLevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action OnCannonLevelChanged;

    private static CannonLevelManager instance;

    private int cannonLevel = 0; // Starting level for the cannon
    private float levelDamageModifier = 1.0f; // Default damage modifier
    private float levelFireRateModifier = 1.0f; // Default fire rate modifier

    private bool isLevelIncreased = false; // Flag to track if the level has been increased


    private void Awake()
    {
        // Subscribe to the player instantiated event
        PlayerHealth.OnPlayerInstantiated += HandlePlayerInstantiated;
    }

    public static CannonLevelManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                GameObject managerObject = GameObject.Find("CannonLevelManager");

                if (managerObject == null)
                {
                    managerObject = new GameObject("CannonLevelManager");
                    instance = managerObject.AddComponent<CannonLevelManager>();
                }
                else
                {
                    instance = managerObject.GetComponent<CannonLevelManager>();
                }

                DontDestroyOnLoad(managerObject);
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public int GetCannonLevel()
    {
        return cannonLevel;
    }

    public void UpdateCannonLevel()
    {
        Debug.Log("UpdateCannonLevel called");
        OnCannonLevelChanged?.Invoke();
    }

    // This method is called externally to increase the cannon level
    public void TryIncreaseCannonLevel()
    {
        
        IncreaseCannonLevel();
    }

    // This method increases the cannon level
    public void IncreaseCannonLevel()
    {
        if (!isLevelIncreased)
        {
            Debug.Log("Attempting to Increase Cannon Level");

            Debug.Log("Increasing Cannon Level");
            cannonLevel++;
            Debug.Log("Increased Cannon Level");
            UpdateCannonLevel();

            isLevelIncreased = true; // Set the flag to true to indicate level increase
        }
    }
    public void ResetCannonLevelManager()
    {
        cannonLevel = 0;
        levelDamageModifier = 1.0f;
        levelFireRateModifier = 1.0f;
        isLevelIncreased = false;
        UpdateCannonLevel(); // Notify subscribers about the reset
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Check if the level has been increased
        if (isLevelIncreased)
        {
            UpdateModifiers();
            isLevelIncreased = false; // Reset the flag
        }
    }

    public float GetCannonLevelDamageModifier()
    {
        return levelDamageModifier;
    }

    public float GetCannonLevelFireRateModifier()
    {
        return levelFireRateModifier;
    }

    private void UpdateModifiers()
    {
        float damageModifier = 1.0f + (cannonLevel * 0.1f);
        float fireRateModifier = 1.0f + (cannonLevel * 0.1f);

        levelDamageModifier = damageModifier;
        levelFireRateModifier = fireRateModifier;

        UpdateCannonModifiers();
    }

    private void UpdateCannonModifiers()
    {
        CannonBullet[] cannonBullets = FindObjectsOfType<CannonBullet>();

        foreach (CannonBullet cannonBullet in cannonBullets)
        {
            IDamageDealer damageDealer = cannonBullet.GetComponent<IDamageDealer>();
            if (damageDealer != null)
            {
                damageDealer.SetDamageModifier(levelDamageModifier);
            }

            if (cannonBullet is IShootingRateModifier shootingRateModifier)
            {
                shootingRateModifier.SetShootingRateModifier(levelFireRateModifier);
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandlePlayerInstantiated()
    {
        // Handle the player instantiated event
        // For example, update the cannon level or perform other setup
        // This method will be called when the player is instantiated.
    }
    

}
```

Comment: How did you observe that "any function there are not being called and work."?   Do you accidentally have two or more different CannonLevelManager objects?  This could happen if you manually created multiple objects with the name CannonLevelManager to your scene, or if other objects accidentally have the CannonLevelManager script attached.  Or maybe even if the first access of Instance was performed by multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There is damage and fire rate modifiers these change the damage inflicted and fire rate with keypress. Also have an instantiator script subscribes to OnCannonLevelChanged?.Invoke() event that activate and deactivate different cannon objects based on the current level. Key press works with tryincreasecannonlevel same as the button. I also created different buttons they did the same, only debug logs appear nothing else changes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're counting on `Update` to call `UpdateModifiers` which will ultimately update fields like `levelDamageModifier`.  But I think you're saying that you can call `UpdateCannonLevel` and you observe that the callback function `OnCannonLevelChanged`, when it calls `GetCannonLevelDamageModifier`, **doesn't see an updated `levelDamageModifier` value**.

If so, this is **because `Update` hasn't been called yet**.

You'll probably want to move the level increasing guard inside your `UpdateModifiers` code like this.

```
    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateModifiers();
    }

    private void UpdateModifiers()
    {
        // Check if the level has been increased
        if (isLevelIncreased)
        {
            float damageModifier = 1.0f + (cannonLevel * 0.1f);
            float fireRateModifier = 1.0f + (cannonLevel * 0.1f);

            levelDamageModifier = damageModifier;
            levelFireRateModifier = fireRateModifier;

            UpdateCannonModifiers();
        }
        isLevelIncreased = false; // Reset the flag
    }
```

And then `UpdateCannonLevel` can be modified to call `UpdateModifiers` immediately after incrementing the level.

```
    public void IncreaseCannonLevel()
    {
        if (!isLevelIncreased)
        {
            cannonLevel++;
            isLevelIncreased = true; // Set the flag to true to indicate level increase
            UpdateModifiers();
        }
    }
```

Comment: These modifications didn't do the job but while I was checking things according to your comment, I tryed to attach the cannon level manager script to another empty game object and it worked. But still I don't understand the issue. Game manager object had many other management scripts attached to it but I can not see what was the interference. Thanks to you  the problem is fixed. Thanks.